# regex isMatch returns false

Tags: java, regex

Original regex: `[v]\d+?\.\d`

Captures the "v{N}.{n}" in strings where {N}/{n} is only a number. I try in code (java) but returns false.

**Code:**

```
  String content = "En este texto hay un documento v4.6.pdf";

  String pattern = "[v]\\d+?\\.\\d";

  boolean isMatch = Pattern.matches(pattern, content);
  System.out.println("The text contains 'v{N}.{n}'? " + isMatch);
```

**Console:**

```
The text contains 'v{N}.{n}'? false
```

Comment: I don't think you want the `?` to be in your pattern.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException because the number after the 'v' can be 1 or 99999999 with 'd+?' i get all the digit until the dot.

Comment: But `\d+` already means "one or more digits". Isn't that exactly what you want? By using `"\\d+?"` you are saying *optionally* one or more digits. If that's the case, why not simply say "zero or more digits" - `"\\d*"` - but I think you'll always have a digit after the "v".

Comment: You're right. I deleted de '"?"'. With '"\\d+"' if the string is '"doc v.3.pdf" 'returns false, the string must contain '"v{number}.{number}"' and using  '"\\d*"' the String can be '"doc v.3.pdf"' and that's an error for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `Pattern.matches()` tries to match the whole string. I.e. as if there was a `^` at the beginning of the pattern and `$` at the end. So you can do any of these two:

#### 1. add `.*` to both end of the pattern:

```
String pattern = ".*[v]\\d+?\\.\\d.*";
```

#### 2. Use `Matcher.find()`:

```
String pattern = "[v]\\d+?\\.\\d";
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = regexPattern.matcher(content);
boolean isMatch = matcher.find();
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj oh, right. That'd be an improvement. I was focusing on fixing his problem.

Answer (score 3):

`matches` tries to match the entire String. You should use `find` method of `Matcher`instead which tries to find a match. Or you could try matching the entire String using `.*` as postfix and prefix.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String content = "En este texto hay un documento v4.6.pdf";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[v]\\d+?\\.\\d");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("found");
    }

}
```

O/P :
`found`

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Yes, that's right. I was just emphasizing that the OP's regex is Ok but he was using the wrong method